# git: why exactly is the claim "git is based on differences between files" wrong?

Tags: git

I know `git add` saves just a new snapshot of a particular file. But I'm a bit confused about the term "snapshot". As I understood git (e.g. [by that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506164/5124117) or [that](http://git-scm.com/book/ch1-3.html)) source, a snapshot is actually a just the difference to the last commit.

Quote from [2](http://git-scm.com/book/ch1-3.html):

> it basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment and stores a reference to that snapshot. To be efficient, if files have not changed, Git doesn’t store the file again, just a link to the previous identical file it has already stored.

That sounds to me exactly like the description of a system based on file differences -.-

**EDIT:**

To be a bit more specific:

I understood, that if a blob isn't modified, the hash isn't changed and therefore used in further commits. It also makes sense to me, that git can detect similarities between blobs and hence eliminate redundancy.

**=>** Would it be equivalent if i would call e.g. vimdiff (just to illustrate the concept) onto a blob and save the output in a new blob?

**=>** How does a changed blob look like that has things in common with other blobs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer**: No, Git always records the entire file.

**Longer answer**: Okay, that's not quite true. *Logically*, Git always records the entire file. In the storage backend, however, Git performs delta compression across *all files* from *all revisions*, so it even detects identical content between *different* files and across the *entire* history of *all* branches, not just the parent commit. And since the network protocol and the storage backend share the same format ("pack files"), you get the same efficiency for `push` and `fetch`.

However, it is important to remember that this is an internal implementation detail of the storage backend. It is *not* a part of the object model. The object model is that each commit contains the *entire* tree.

This is Git's object model:

- *blob*: a bytestream. Basically, a file, but *only* its contents. It doesn't have a name. In this way, Git works like a Unix filesystem, files don't have names, rather directories associate names with files.
- *tree*: a flat(!!!) list of `(mode, name, {tree|blob})` triples. This is the equivalent to a Unix directory. It associates names and modes (mainly executable or not) with blobs or trees. I.e. trees can be recursive.
- *commit*: a pointer to a tree and a pointer to zero, one, or many parent commits. Also contains a datestamp and two name strings (author and committer) and most importantly, the commit message.
- (local tag): technically, not a Git object. Just a local file pointing to a commit.
- *annotated tag*: contains a pointer to a commit, a name, and an annotation message.
- *signed tag*: contains an annotated tag(???) and a digital signature [not sure about this one, is built on top of an annotated tag or does it duplicate it?]
- *note*: a piece of text that can be attached to any Git object. This can be used to add arbitrary user-defined metadata to any Git object, e.g. a CI server could attach code coverage results to commits or a bug tracker could attach links to tickets to commits which fix a bug, a web server could attach MIME types to blobs, a release management system could attach go/no-go votes to annotated tags, …

Note that *only* blobs actually contain file data. The rest is just pointers. And blobs don't have names, which means that as long as a blob has the same content, it is the same blob, and thus only exists once in the object store. In fact, it even exists only once in the entire Git universe! For example, the FSF's GPL `COPYING` file, as long as you keep it unmodified, will be the exact same blob, even in totally unrelated repositories!

Comment: What do you mean by "flat" in your tree list entry?

Comment: I mean that the tree doesn't actually store a tree, it stores a list of pointers. The "depth" of the tree comes from being defined recursively, i.e. the fact that the pointers are allowed to point to trees as well as blobs. That's not really unique, that's basically the standard way to define a tree data structure and is also of course how Unix directories work, but some people think that the entire tree is stored in a single object, which is not the case.

Comment: I understood, that if a blob isn't modified, the hash isn't changed and therefore used in further commits.
It also makes sense to me, that git can detect similarities between blobs and hence eliminate redundancy.

=> Would it be equivalent if i would call e.g. vimdiff (just to illustrate the concept) onto a blob and save the output in a new blob?
=> How does a changed blob look like that has things in common with other blobs?

Comment: A signed tag is just an annotated tag that contains a signature.  Also, notes are not a special object type, they're just the same objects, stored in the `refs/notes/` namespace and using "pathnames" that correspond to commit or blob IDs (so that `git log`, or anything else that wants to find a note given a commit, can find the correct note easily).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "based on differences between files". Some systems (like hg or darcs) do not store the whole files, but only diffs (patches) between their versions, so that every version can be restored by applying the full diff history up to the given commit.

Git, on the contrary, stores each version of each file as an independent blob as if it was created from scratch. But, exactly as the book says, if a file is not updated, nothing will be written.

Comment: I think that book is misleading. A commit stores a pointer to a tree, a tree stores pointers to blobs and trees, a blob is just the content of the file. If the file isn't changed, then the blob is the same as before, and it is already in the object store, so there is nothing to do. But that is not really a function of the commit.

Comment: I've refined my original question to address that confusion.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Can I clarify - so if you store FileA and FileB in Commit 1 (C1). Then you modify FileA and make another commit (C2). C2 creates a new blob object representing the updated contents of FileA. And it does not create a new blob object for FileB - it just points to C1's version of FileB. Is this correct?

Comment: @Lou: Let's put it a different way: in Git, everything is based on addresses. The address of an object is the hash of its content. So, two blobs with the same content have the same address and are thus not even two blobs, they are one and the same. This does not only apply if you have duplicate files in a commit or if you have files that do not change between commits. You can theoretically store multiple repositories using the same backend object store, and there will even be only one copy in that. As an extreme case, you can imagine that there is only one single copy of the `GPL` license file

Comment: … in the entirety of GitHub because every repository that uses the GPL will have a `LICENSE` file with the same content, thus with the same address, and thus there will be only one single copy of this blob across all versions of all branches of all repositories in all of GitHub. This is somewhat exaggerated of course, because I assume GitHub has boundaries between the free and the Enterprise version of the service, and that it has redundancies and backups built in, etc.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "So, two blobs with the same content have the same address and are thus not even two blobs, they are one and the same" - With you so far. But then if you change the file, a new blob is created right? So in my example, C2.FileA has a new blob because it was modified, but C2.FileB just points to the original blob stored in C1?