# Meaning git commit

Tags: git

Git documentation states:

> Every time you commit, or save the state of your project in Git, it basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment

What does it basically mean "to take a picture"?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/6309

Comment: Where exactly in the documentation?

Comment: This accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455666/git-why-exactly-is-the-claim-git-is-based-on-differences-between-files-wrong/33455768#33455768 has a good summary of what is a git commit internally.

Comment: link:https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: In other words it takes a snapshot. That means that it saves the state of all files staged for the commit (files added to the index - e.g. with `git add`).

Answer (score 0):

It asks all the files in the repository to stand in a line and say "cheese". Then, an x-ray picture is taken, showing all the binary data.

This binary data is then used to determine the state at which your folder was at that point, in order to re-create it later (on a different location) or to make diff's.

Answer (score 0):

Make a commit and then run `git log -1 --pretty=raw` and you will see `tree xxxxxx` in the output. The tree is the sha1 of a snapshot of the current git repo . If two trees have the same sha1, we can be sure they have the same contents. You could run `git ls-tree sha1` to see what's the tree composed of or what the snapshot has. You will see a list of trees and blobs, sometimes also commits, with their sha1s. A blob refers to a file. A tree refers to a folder. You could run `git cat-file -p blob-sha1` or `git show blob-sha1` to see the content of the blob. Every blob is a snapshot of a file in different times. If a file is changed, its blob and sha1 changes too. But with the same content, we can always get the same sha1, by `git hash-object`. So basically, a commit refers to a tree (the root folder of the git repo) which represents the state of the git repo. A tree is composed of other trees (sub directories) and blobs (files) in the git repo. When we make a commit, it records the state of the git repo, what the folders and files are like at that time. With the commit, we can rebuild the whole git repo which is described by the trees and blobs.